# Selection of inputs from UTXO's who are not used by other unconfirmed transaction

Tags: transactions, utxo, transaction-input, utxo-set

How to prevent selection of unspent transaction from UTXO's which is already used in another unconfirmed transaction ?

I am fetching list of UTXO's from here -
https://mempool.space/testnet/docs/api/rest#get-address-utxo

Trying to send bitcoins from native segwit address to all other types of addresses using bitcoinjs-lib in node js.

From list of UTXO's I am selecting the inputs as required.
If the first input is already selected for a transaction which is unconfirmed how can I prevent the selection of that first input in next transaction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing a wallet it is probably a bad idea to rely on a trusted third party to provide a list of UTXOs. I would expect any wallet application to keep a local list of UTXO's for which it has the corresponding private keys.

Then you mark UTXO's as provisionally committed when you transmit a transaction consuming them. When creating transactions you avoid selecting local UTXOs you have previously marked as provisionally committed.

If a transaction doesn't get confirmed in a reasonable time (days, weeks?) you could unmark the appropriate UTXOs in your local list.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe maintain a list/map of "reserved" UTXO's -- meaning UTXO's you're already using in a unconfirmed transaction.

Once transaction is confirmed you can update your list/map of reserved UTXO's.